# Writing an app that previews the result of a small part of code

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This may seem strange, so I will try to explain it as best I can:

I want to write an application for OS X that will accept some code as an input and will produce a visual output. The input will be in Objective C and the output will be the output that this code describes.

The output may be text or graphics based, it doesn't matter. What matters is that I don't know how can I make this input be handled as Objective C code and be executed by the system as such. I have a big experience with Objective C, but I hadn't had the chance to get involved with something like this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to show a visualization of the code (the abstract syntax Tree) or do you want to show the output of the code (console/graphics)?

Comment: I want to do the latter, show the output of the code.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to:

1. Take Objective-C input
2. Parse it
3. And show its structure to the user in a visually digestible form.

Now the hard part is parsing it - for that you'll need a compiler front-end, possibly [LLVM-clang.](http://clang.llvm.org/) When you have an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the code, you can walk that tree and easily construct some graphics or structured, human-readable text to describe what the code does.

Edit: so you want to actually compile and execute that code. Then you have to go one step further and compile the code then run it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want to show its structure, but its result (visual/console).

Comment: I want it for OS X, as I have written, not iOS.

Comment: @ChristosSotiriou yes, sorry. Fixed it.